# SWIFT: unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell error when displaying a dictionary in a table view with multiple sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7

I'm trying to a guest list for multiple events in a Table View.  See storyboard below -

[image]

I've created four sections, and have named all of the cell identifiers "cell". When I run the app, I get the following error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class RSVPTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var names = ["Event 1": ["Guest 1", "Guest 2", "Guest 3"], "Event 2": ["Guest 1", "Guest 2"]]

struct Objects {

    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String]!
}

var objectArray = [Objects]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for (key, value) in names {
        print("\(key) -> \(value)")
        objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value))
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return objectArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return objectArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return objectArray[section].sectionName
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]

    return cell


}

}
```

Comment: You set the cells up as "Static Cells". Instead, you want "Dynamic Prototypes"

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. Santa Claus just came to town!

Answer (score 1):

`Static Cells` are intended for...well...*static* content. Given that you have a *dynamic* array you want to use to set cell content, you should use the `Dynamic Prototypes` cell type.

After giving the prototype cell (you should only need one) an identifier, you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Dynamic types as you actually need a custom cell to use your array.
please do select Prototype from your tableview's attribute Content. and make your custom cell.